# Racket merging two images (background picture with another one) image->color-list

Tags: image, merge, racket

I have  one question about Racket. How can I merge two images (first, into lists and then from lists into one image). I found a procedure:

```
(define (outerProcedure)
  (define (colourLists bg fg)
    (let ((color-lst1 (image->color-list bg))
          (color-lst2 (image->color-list fg)))
      <inner body>))
  <outer body>
  ; colourLists is called at some point in the outer body
  (colourLists bg fg)) ; bg and fg were defined somewhere else
```

But I cound not begin with it, Can You please help me?

Regards
Helena

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to turn each image into a list of colors. The [`overlay`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html?q=overlay#%28def._%28%28lib._2htdp%2Fimage..rkt%29._overlay%29%29) function and friends will compose images for you:

```
(define (compose-two-images img1 img2)
  (overlay img1 img2))
```

I'm not sure exactly how this fits into the sample code you posted, you may want to be more specific about what `outerProcedure` is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
#lang racket
(require 2htdp/image)

(define (color-add c1 c2)
  (make-color (quotient (+ (color-red   c1) (color-red   c2)) 2)
              (quotient (+ (color-green c1) (color-green c2)) 2)
              (quotient (+ (color-blue  c1) (color-blue  c2)) 2)))

(define width 100)
(define height 100)
(define background (rectangle width height "solid" "transparent"))
(define image1 (overlay background (rectangle 50 50 "solid" "yellow")))
(define image2 (overlay background (triangle  100    "solid" "blue")))
(define colors1 (image->color-list image1))
(define colors2 (image->color-list image2))
(define colors3 (map color-add colors1 colors2))

(define image3 (color-list->bitmap colors3 width height))
image3
```